# Am I required to cast flags or close votes when asked to?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

I have some private reasons for not wanting to press "punishment" buttons like `flag` or `close`. However, I am occasionally asked by moderators to do so.

In that situation, *ought* I press those buttons, or do I have free will on the matter?

Comment: What do you mean ? You want to know if you must spend time in policing SO or if you're free to not do it (for whatever reason you want) ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but... what are you asking?

Comment: That is a false dichotomy. You both ought to (when the question is unanswerable, extremely localised etc) *and* have free will in the matter.

Comment: "But occasionally asked by moderators to do so." By whom, when?

Comment: Press those buttons or lose all your reputation.

Comment: What do you mean by "moderator"? Mods can close questions at will, so there would never be any reason they would have to ask you to vote to close. Do you just mean other regular users who happen to be loudmouths and/or have lots of rep? (Also, if you're looking at these and seeing "punishment buttons," I humbly suggest that you're doing it wrong.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can press them or not press them. Your call. Just don't ask the mods to press them for you.

Also, you may want to consider pressing the down-vote button now and then. Just to keep the cobwebs off of it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all flag button is not a punishment. You can flag any post for any reason. e.g. A user (except the author of the post) who has less than 3K reputation can flag a question to reopen. This is not a punishment.

Also, voting to close depends on you. If you don't like to vote to close a question than you are not forced to do that. But if the question is not suitable for the site the question will surely be closed by other users.